# Pycharm doesnt show static fields while code completion using Qt5

Tags: python, qt, autocomplete, pyqt, pycharm

I am using PyQt5 (ver 5.15.6)
While accessing some static fields like Qt.WindingFill Qt.NoBrush or QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable the auto code completion (ctrl + space) doesn't show other options (it doesn't even show my option) while the interpreter can run the code successfully and after correctly writing the static methods name pycharm doesn't complain. Why is the reason ?

example code:

```
import math
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class QDMGraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._color_background = QColor("#123456")
        self.scene_width, self.scene_height = 64000, 64000
        self.setSceneRect(-self.scene_width//2, -self.scene_height//2, self.scene_width, self.scene_height)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(self._color_background)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        super().drawBackground(painter, rect)



class NodeEditorWnd(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        # crate graphics scene
        self.grScene = QDMGraphicsScene()
        # create graphics view
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.view.setScene(self.grScene)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setWindowTitle("test123")
        self.show()
        self.addDebugContent()

    def addDebugContent(self):
        greenBrush = QBrush(Qt.green)
        outlinePen = QPen(Qt.black)
        outlinePen.setWidth(2)
        rect = self.grScene.addRect(-100, -100, 80, 100, outlinePen, greenBrush)
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        text = self.grScene.addText("testtext")
        text.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        text.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        text.setDefaultTextColor(QColor.fromRgbF(1.0,.7,.1))
        widget1 = QPushButton("hello wo")
        proxy1 = self.grScene.addWidget(widget1)
        proxy1.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        proxy1.setPos(0,30)
        widget2 = QTextEdit()
        proxy2 = self.grScene.addWidget(widget2)
        proxy2.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        proxy2.setPos(0,60)
        line = self.grScene.addLine(-200, -200, 400, -100, outlinePen)
        line.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        line.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = NodeEditorWnd()
```

Comment: The code completion has **nothing** to do with the validity of the program. They are just *suggestions* to ease up coding: if the IDE doesn't suggest a completion, it doesn't mean that the program won't run - and vice versa. Look up for the pycharm configuration with virtualenv, installed libraries and python paths. Besides, there are no static methods in your code.

Comment: @musicamante yeah I should fix it with static fields* also my problem is with code completion not for validity checking or interpreting. pycharm uses the projects own virtualenv and python packages tab below clearly shows pyQt5 installed. Pycharm shows suggestions on functions but static fields like Qt.WindingFill, Qt.NoBrush doesn't come up. I would like to know why